# Crear una web API First

Tags: apache, api, rest

Estoy creado una web, separando el servidor de la web en si, ahora me encuentro en un dilema, si tengo un **Apache** con el **php** que ofrece la API y otro con la web que consume la API. Pero estos dos Apache han de estar en un solo PC.

¿Van separados por **puertos**, la API el **8080** y la web el **80**?

¿O este tipo de programación **API first**, obliga a tener dos servidores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te permite este tipo de arquitectura es desacoplar el backend (API) del frontend (Web) lo cual te permitiría en un futuro poder atender distintos canales (Mobile, Físicos, Etc) desde un mismo API, una posible configuración es la que mencionas.

- **Servidor:**

  - Apache

    - 80 (WEB)
    - 8080 (API)

Otra posible es:

- **Servidor1:**

  - Apache:

    - 80 (API)
- **Servidor2:**

  - Apache:

    - 80 (WEB)

Comment: interesante, pero en la primera opción, también a de haber 2 "Apache", o con uno se pueden atender a dos peticion es distintas?

Comment: Basta solo uno en realidad, solo debes configurar los vhosts para apuntar a una carpeta distinta según el puerto.